# Form not submitting even after I have removed "required" field - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have about 8 fields (4 required and 4 optional) in my form and I have tested every field with "required" and other forms of validation rules.

Now I have removed the "required" rule in the optional ones but when I submit the form, the optional fields won't let me, the error I get on each is **"The field is invalid"**.

Can someone please tell what needs to be done? All I want is 4 to be required and other 4 to be optional. Also, I did place other validation rules in the optional ones like "min, max and regex".

```
         `$this->validate($request,[
        'firstname' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/|min:2|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/|min:2|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:clients',
        'telephone' => 'regex:^\+?([0-9]{2})-?([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{6,7})*$^',
        'job_title' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z. ]*$/|min:7|max:255',
        'nationality' => 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/|min:4|max:255',
        'dob' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/|max:255',
        'interests' => 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z,. ]*$/|min:10|max:255',
        ]);
        `
```

As you can see, the ones not having required field are the ones not letting me submit the form.

Comment: Can you please post your form code and the data you are sending?

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: That error message wording would seem like it is something wrong with the regex, tbh don't bother with the regexes and just validate them to strings

Comment: But is it safe to validate them to strings alone? How about the phone number which I specifically want that way? And do I just write the word "string" to validate them to string?